# How to combine array within another array using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array named arr and within that array, I have another array.My question is, how to combine this two array?

```
 var arr=["1","2","[3,4]","5"]
```

My output should be like this:

```
  1,2,3,4,5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output? An array? If `flatMap` is supported, then `arr.flatMap((subArray) => JSON.parse(subArray))` will work and produce `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: @Xufox Just need to print the values

Comment: Please, edit the post by either correcting that you have a string within your array or that you have an actual array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use spread syntax `...` with `map` and `JSON.parse` methods.

```js
var arr = ["1","2","[3,4]","5"]
var result = [].concat(...arr.map(e => JSON.parse(e)))
console.log(...result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have an actual array and not a string you can flatten like this

```js
var arr=["1","2",["3","4"],"5"]
var flat = [].concat(...arr)
console.log(flat)
```

Comment: But they _do_ have a string `"[3,4]"`, not `["3", "4"]`.

Comment: @Xufox "I have an array named arr and within that array, I have another array"

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to string and further replace the square brackets using `replace(/[\[|\]]/g,'')`:

```js
var arr=["1","2","[3,4]","5"];
var res = arr.toString().replace(/[\[|\]]/g,'');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to flat an array like this `[1,2,[3,4],5]` or this `[1,[2,[[3,4],5]]]` into this`[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]` here a pretty general and short solution:

```js
var arr = [1, [2, [[3, 4], 5]]];

var newArr = JSON.parse("[" + JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/\[|\]/g, "") + "]");

console.log(newArr)
```

Or [.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) if browser supports it:

```
var arr = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr.flat();
console.log(arr)
```